# Outlook 2010 OWA cannot delete emails

Tags: exchange, microsoft

I have an Exchange Server 2010 setup Version: 14.03.0382.000.

Through the outlook web access OWA the send/receive email works but all move mail operations and deletions fail with the following error:

the action you tried to perform couldn't be completed because there's a configuration problem

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1446907-exchange-2010-owa-error-when-trying-to-delete-items

Mentioned solutions don't help with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS manager, right-click Default Web Site and select Edit Bindings, then check if the correct certificate is assigned to the HTTPS service on port 443.

Also check the EWS VD settings: Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory | fl